# Compile SWI Prolog code into Windows executable - parser Grails3 project

Tags: windows, prolog, cygwin, swi-prolog

I am trying to build parser Grails3 project https://github.com/RichardMoot/Grail whose tutorial is http://www.labri.fr/perso/moot/tutorial/install.html. It is said in tutorial that nix system is required or Cygwin on Windows is required. But is it really needed? Is it possible to build Windows executable from the Prolog code using only Windows installation of SWI Prolog?

Can I assume that makefile for this project is intended for some Prolog compiler?

I tried to build Grails3 with Cygwin but it says that there is nothing to do and Cygwin installer does not list any Prolog (none at all!) software of Prolog compiler. So - maybe I can just use SWI Prolog as compiler?

***Progress report:*** I tried to install on Ubuntu, but my make gives some strange output and no executable is created, only g3 txt file is created:

```
osboxes@osboxes:~/Homes/Grail-master$ sudo make
cd source ; /bin/sed -e 's,@graildatadir\@,/home/osboxes/Homes/Grail-master/share/Grail,g' -e 's,@grailbindir\@,/home/osboxes/Homes/Grail-master/bin,g' g3 > g3.tmp
cd source ; mv -f g3.tmp g3
cd source ; chmod a+x g3
```

So, even after "make install" I cannot run g3 command because this file is not recognized as a command. So, I don't know whether my output from make is good or bad.

Comment: Did you tried *GrailLight* from the same page ? It just requires swipl

Comment: Also on Ubuntu 16.04 the provided installation (autotools based) doesn't work.
At least, I've been unable to run, but had a look at the SW, and I think there are high chances you can simply open the source and run in from swipl.exe (XPCE is very well integrated into)

Comment: I am trying to install it on Ubuntu Virtual Box image, I added Progress Report to my question.

Comment: g3 should be the executable, so an extension .exe is required, also with Cygwin. Should it be produced by swipl -c g3.pl -o g3, after g3.pl has been patched with installation info ?

Comment: I tried on Windows 10, but sources aren't loadable in simple way, sorry...

Answer (score 2):

In Windows, a file is recognized as a command file when it has the .exe suffix.
A second indication is the first two bytes in the file, when you visualize it in notepad.exe or any other file editor, it must be "MZ". These bytes are set by the compiler/linker when it creates the file.

Swipl has evolved over time. What you read on some pages may no longer apply to the current version. So it's very complicated to decipher the internet.

Some Swipl docs say it's a compiler that produces intermediate code (Swipl people call it "saved state") which is not executable code or recognizable command.

I just tried

> swipl --goal=main --stand_alone=true -o myprog -c test.pl

Test.pl being

> append([], X, X). append([X|Xs], Y, [X|Z]) :-     append(Xs, Y, Z).
>
> main :-   append([a,b],[c,d],X),      write(X),   get_single_char(Y),
> halt.

I did receive a myprog.exe and it's executable, with the magic code MZ as the first byte. So in 2020, Swipl is a full compiler prolog to executable binary code. Bravo!

220 ko for my simple program is kind of huge, but it's ok for me! For deployment in Windows, you may still have to package the different dll files with the exe, as usual. There are ways of packaging your exe and the dll's into one compressed file, so it becomes a fully stand-alone exe.

- winzip self extracting executable
- iexpress (part of windows 8+)

And it's possible to create a stand-alone console application with the source code of Chat_80 in a file of 1.5 Mo. Beautiful !