# Compiling Prolog to exe file

Tags: prolog, swi-prolog

this is to politely ask you how a prolog code can be converted to executable file format (.exe). Please help me step by step, I am new to prolog and I am doing a project using Prolog. I am windows user and I have only swi-prolog installed in my pc, I am able to write and compile my code, but I am not able to convert it to exe file.

Thank you for your time and willingness.

Comment: Just follow the steps from the [SWI documentation](https://www.swi-prolog.org/FAQ/WinExe.html)

Comment: Dear, I tried following the SWI documentation but I am not able to create exe file through the documentation. Please if you have an example for clarification how to follow the documentation. help me. Thank you once again.

Comment: Show us the sample code and steps you followed when it didn't work

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: This has been asked. Check this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48085295/compile-swi-prolog-code-into-windows-executable-parser-grails3-project?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

You can make your file executable in the following way:

1. Go to SWI - Prolog console and make sure that you are on the same directory as the file you want to execute.
2. Then type to your console qsave_program( Filename, []). For example, if I have a file "test.pl", I would type qsave_program(test,[]). Inside the empty list, you can put attributes according to your needs. See here for more information: [SWI-PROLOG DOCUMENTATION](https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=qsave_program/2)